# Does jumping around in a program hurt performance due to caching issues

Tags: performance, caching

I know there are memory caches so that using values from a lot of disparate points in memory causes cache misses and hurts performance. As a program is executed is it actually loaded from memory into the cpu in small blocks similar to an L1 cache? I ask because presumably then jumping around in memory frequently would cause misses on this cache and hurt performance. So I guess it is two questions: is there such an "execution cache" and does jumping around frequently hurt performance.

P.S. Not sure what appropriate tags are for this other than performance and caching.

P.P.S. An example situation might be an otherwise tight loop containing a lot of nested `if`s and `else`s where the end result at the bottom of each if and else nest is only a small amount of code.

Comment: Unless you need your code to be blindingly fast, you probably don't need to worry about cache misses.  There are much easier ways to optimize your program.

Comment: For 99.9% of my code, I don't care about this. This is only is relevant in those few, rare, but critical parts that do need to be really, really fast and the question of how to quickly handle a large number of small interrelated cases with high performance is one I am currently facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This cache is called the instruction cache. Exhausting it can have severe implications for performance. This is the reason that inlining functions is not always beneficial. The inlined functions will be faster but the bloated code size might drive the hot path out of the I-cache.

The Linux kernel deverlopers mailing list has interesting discussions about this topic.

Comment: So in your example you mean that frequent calls to inlined functions might slow down code because the a frequently called small function would be loaded into the instruction cache and remain there, instead of bloating the code as an inline function causing cache misses because the same inline function is being loaded multiple places into the instruction cache. Correct?

Comment: How big is an instruction cache likely to be now days (e.g. last I knew I think 16K and 4M were on about the right order of magnitude for an L1 and L2 cache if I'm remembering correctly)?

Comment: @JohnRobertson I was unable to comprehend the first sentence of yours ;-) Too long, too nested. I was trying to say that inlining a function which is quite cold can damage performance because the hot code might get evicted from the cache. Inlining (most often) creates CPU instructions. The more often you inline the more instructions you get from the same program. For the same reason compilers support optimizing for size. My Core i7's I-cache is 32kb in size. It is tiny. Not sure if sending even a single UDP packet would fully stay in cache.